# How can I get ubuntu to recognize DisplayPort after upgrading kernels?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, display-resolution

After installing a new instance of Ubuntu 20.04 on a newly built PC, everything was working perfectly for about a week but sometimes on boot my wifi wouldn't connect and I'd have to reboot to get it working. I was doing some problem solving and,as per a suggested fix, was led to this page where I decided to install a suggested kernel:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I went to the newest link (https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7-rc6/) and installed the following:

linux-headers-5.7.0-050700rc6_5.7.0-050700rc6.202005172030_all.deb

linux-image-unsigned-5.7.0-050700rc6-generic_5.7.0-050700rc6.202005172030_amd64.deb

linux-modules-5.7.0-050700rc6-generic_5.7.0-050700rc6.202005172030_amd64.deb

When I rebooted, my resolution was stuck on 640x480 4:3. Previous to these downloads, I was running at 2560x1440 and had no issues. Being that the resolutions don't match up, it is very hard to use my screen. Additionally, on reboot, I saw the errors in the attached picture.

[Errors on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DYOP.jpg)

MoBo: MSI MPG x570 Gaming Plus

CPU: Ryzen 5 3600

GPU: ASUS TUF Gaming Geforce RTX 2060

Monitor: Samsung LC27JG56QQNXZA

Happy to list any other info if needed. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You installed a very new kernel, but your graphics driver has been build with another on. That won't work. 
It is not a good idea to replace the "main stream" kernel with some arbitrary kernel if you don't know exactly what that means.

To get your display back, select the "old" kernel in grub. When you've started with the old kernel,back in your dekstop, remove the new kernel - you can't use it with your setup.
Then you should ask a new question about your wifi.